# JQuery UI Tabs Background Color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, background-color, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to change the background of the tab area.. like, You have a list of tabs, and I know how to change the color of each individual tab, but I was wondering if you could change the color of the background of all of that. Normally it's the dark gray color, and the tabs are the light gray. I was wanted to change those colors to maybe either a light blue, or light green, and I've tried changing the CSS of everything I could find relating to the UI Tabs, and none of them worked.

Comment: Did you try the theme roller? http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ also a screenshot of what part exactly you are trying to change would help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to change `.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav`.

CSS:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav
{
background: lightblue;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel /* just in case you want to change the panel */
{
background: blue;
}
```

Comment: jQuery UI uses more than just a color for backgrounds, I believe this will remove the semitransparent image overlay that gives the beveled effect. A better solution would be to use [themeroller](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and either choose a different theme or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the background of div also . below is example -->

```
<div id="tabs" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(204, 204, 204);">
 <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Product-Tweets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Popular Product</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1"> tab 1 content </div>
 <div id="tab-2"> tab 2 content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is better to use css class because hard coding styles does not scale well when you try to maintain the system.  It is ok for a demo.

Comment: The other solution did not work in my case, this one did.