# JQuery UI tabs background - navigation stays white

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the background behind the tabs completely. I took the [basic tabs example](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and added this code, as advised e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316048/684229):

```
body { background-color: #ddddff; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav, .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    background: #ddddff;
}
```

but unfortunatelly the navigation pane stays white for the active tab:

[image]

Seems that navigation pane for both active and inactive tabs are done by images. How to use jqueryUI tabs then? Do I really have to create images for each background color I want to use?

I have jquery-ui 1.10.3, tested on theme "UI lightness" and "smoothnes" both with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active{your active color}` this should have your background color

Comment: wow, I don't know how this works but it works! Seems to somehow override the images that are used. Thanks!

Comment: only the last one matters: `.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active`

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for transparent background - I posted it as a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/21031876/684229. Would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your tabs background to this.

```
 background: #ddddff !important;
```

Comment: or if you are using a local version of jquery ui, you could go edit the jquery ui.css file directly